# Reach shared folder that is 'upstream', behind router

Tags: wireless-networking, network-shares

We have a local network that has several shared network drives. To provide Wi-Fi, we have added a router (TP-Link) that simply serves as an access point.

What I would like to do is to access the shared drives on the LAN, from a computer connected to the WiFi. Since the WiFi router creates its local subnet, it can't find the shared folder.

Is there a way to reach these folders from the WiFi anyway? If not, is there a way to use a router as a switch while still providing WiFi access?

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to access the server by specifying its IP address like `\\10.10.9.100\` -- but that may or may not be successful.

Your best option is to configure your TP-Link for "bridged" or "AP" mode (if possible), which will disable the routing function and cause it to simply broadcast the same subnet as the rest of your LAN, allowing you to access shares as you would with any other PC on the LAN.